# What are common header navigation items on mobile websites in Korea?

Tags: navigation, menu, language

I am not sure if I should keep our standard header or make some modifications. For example, do certain colors have significant meaning? is a certain eye movement more natural?

What is the equivalent word for "menu" in Korean? in the actual alphabet. Or is there a symbol that is more commonly encountered by users in Korea.

sorry if this question sounds ignorant, but just trying to be sensitive to our international audience.

Comment: hamburger button!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no significant difference in UI design in Korea. For example, take a look at [this mobile version](http://m.naver.com) of a popular Korean site 'Naver', it is not that much different. They also use the hamburger menu icon, etc.

Also, menu in Korean is `메뉴`.

Comment: Do you know the html entity equivalent of the Korean word for menu?

Comment: Should be `&#xba54;&#xb274;`.